# Modal Bootstrap issue when calling from code behind in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am having an issue with the Modal component of bootstrap.

The problem is that when I try to call the modal from the code behind it is showing up but the modal loses its efects, the background does not turn gray and the modal does not slide from the top.

Please find below my code.

```
<div class="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" runat="server" 
      visible="false" id="myModalServicios" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
      aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">            
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">       
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">            
    </div>
</div>
```

Code Behind:

```
myModalServices.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your markup, the div's id is `myModalServicios` but your code behind references `myModalServices`

Comment: typing mistake, actually in my code i have the divs id as myModalServices, so i guess thats not the problem, thanks anyway!